# swift function return object or nil

Tags: ios, swift, function, swift2

I have a method in class:

```
func myFunc() -> Any?
{
    let fetchRequest        = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Product")
    fetchRequest.predicate  = NSPredicate(format: "shopitem == %@", self.objectID)
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1;
    do
    {
       fetchResults = try self.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Product]
    }
    catch
    {
       fatalError("Fetching from the store failed")
    }

    if fetchResults.count > 0
    {
       return fetchResults.first
    }
    return nil
}
```

Then i call this method in another class. But how to check what object returned from it:

```
let product = MyClass.myFunc() as! Product
cell.productTitleLabel.text = product.product_title
```

This code returns error, if my method return nil.

Comment: Lookup `as?` (the *optional* cast) and `if let` (optional binding) in the Swift book ...

Comment: Is there a special reason that your function returns `Any?` instead of `Product?` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution would be to do a simple check before setting your product variable:

```
if let product = MyClass.myFunc() as? Product {
   cell.productTitleLabel.text = product.product_title
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can handle this scenario using conditional type casting. (Refer [Type Casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID338)):

```
if let product = MyClass.myFunc() as? Product
{
   cell.productTitleLabel.text = product.product_title 
}
```

Also if you need to check the type of the returned value you can use like:

```
var product = MyClass.myFunc()
if product is Product
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I don't think this is *optional chaining*.

Comment: @MartinR: No, you are not. You are correct. I've edited my answer with reference